# How can I create a more detailed array with objects | Swift

Tags: swift

Essentially I have been creating the following simple String/Int arrays to record info
into an array set (which of course checks for duplicates before appending) how can I record an ID alongside the string to create a JSON array?

**Currently doing the following:**

```
var myArray = Set<String>()
myArray.insert("Example1")

["Example1","Example2","Example3"]
```

**Example of what I would like to achieve.**

```
[{"myexample":"Example2","id":1},{"myexample":"Example3","id":2}]
```

Comment: Although you could do what you're seeking, you might want to consider creating `struct` to model your data. It could be, for example, `struct Model { var title: String; var id: Int }`

Comment: I have updated my post with the proper format of the JSON array I am trying to create. Can you please show how I would append to this array using struct?

Comment: @StephanieSmith I see you're using a `Set`, but you've named your varibale `myArray`. So you want each of your item (`{"myexample":"Example2","id":1}`) to be unique?

Comment: @justintime Yes it must be unique before being inserted

Comment: `Set` already takes care of uniqueness, it'll only insert if that item isn't already present. In @jnpdx 's answer, `myArray` needs to be a `Set` and the `Model` struct needs to conform to `Hashable`.

Comment: A Set is a Set, not an Array. Your question title, and your code, talk about arrays but create sets. Don't do that. They are different animals. For one thing, Sets are unordered, but arrays are ordered (and offer subscript lookup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `struct` that conforms to `Codable` to represent your data:

```
struct Model : Codable, Hashable {
    var myexample: String
    var id: Int
}

var mySet = Set([Model(myexample: "Example2", id: 1),
               Model(myexample: "Example3", id: 2)])
mySet.insert(Model(myexample: "Example4", id: 3))

do {
    let json = try JSONEncoder().encode(mySet)
    print(String(data: json, encoding: .utf8)!)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the redundant question, how can I append new data to this Model?

Comment: Do you mean "how do I append items to the array" or "how do I add more fields to the struct"?

Comment: How do I append items to the array?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show adding an item to the array

Comment: Thank you, also to clarify from my original question I was using a Set to insert only unique values, how can I ensure the same occurs here?

Comment: Updated to show using `Set`

Comment: @jnpdx Why is your struct Codable?

Comment: @justintime because the OP specifically asked for creating a JSON string from the data

Comment: @StephanieSmith what's your end goal? array of JSON objects? or a complete JSON string?

Comment: The end result should not have quotes surrounding it, the end result should look like the following: `[{"myexample":"Example2","id":1},{"myexample":"Example3","id":2}]`

Comment: My example yields this: `[{"id":2,"myexample":"Example3"},{"id":3,"myexample":"Example4"},{"id":1,"myexample":"Example2"}]` -- this is what you're looking for, correct? Keep in mind that `Set` is inherently unordered as are JSON properties in an object.

Comment: You would create a completely empty one by using `var mySet = Set<Model>()` (assuming you're using `Model` like in my code). I don't know what `selectedIssuesStruct` is in your example. If you have additional questions, please consider starting a new issue, as we're getting beyond the scope of your original question. If my answer has resolved the original issue, please consider marking it as correct with the green checkmark and using the up arrow to upvote if you found it helpful.